# Object reference not set to an instance of an object with no NULL fields present

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following code in my CMS 3.0 project

SurveyController.cs

```
private BuisnessSurveyEntities bsdb = new BuisnessSurveyEntities();

[HttpGet]
public ViewResult BizSurveyCDF()
{
  var bquery = from b in bsdb.form_field
               where b.ID != null        // int
               where b.DATID != null     // int
               where b.CAPTION != null   // string
               select new {b.ID, b.DATID, b.CAPTION};

  ViewData["BZQUESTIONS"] = new SelectList(bquery,"ID","DATID","CAPTION");
  return View();
}
```

form_field.cs model

```
public virtual string ID {GET; SET;}
public virtual string DATID
{
  get{return _dATID;}
  set{_dATID = value;}
}
private string _dATID = "\'\'";
```

BizSurveyCDF.cshtml

```
@model IEnumberable<CMS.Models.form_field>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      DATID
    </th>
    <th>
      CAPTION
    </th>
  </tr>
  @foreach(var item in Model)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DATID)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CAPTION)
      </td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

Now my issue is when I run it i get the following error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

and the offending line is
@foreach(var item in Model)

I have gone through the entire table and replaced all NULL values with something and am still receiving this error.  So far everything I have read says it is having issues with NULL values but as I already stated I have gotten rid of all null values.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could be the LINQ is getting executed out of scope. So I reckon Oded could well be right. Try executing ToArray() or ToList() on the result of the query before handing it to the view?

Comment: do you have CAPTION in form_field.cs model?

Comment: How would I determine if the bsdb is null?  Yes, CAPTION is in the model.  I will research Balthy's suggestion.

Comment: hey did you see my answer, did it worked?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, pass the model to the view and don't create a new object in the query, select the full form_field object.

```
public ViewResult BizSurveyCDF()
{
  var bquery = from b in bsdb.form_field
               where b.ID != null        // int
               where b.DATID != null     // int
               where b.CAPTION != null   // string
               select b;

  //ViewData["BZQUESTIONS"] = new SelectList(bquery,"ID","DATID","CAPTION");
  return View(bquery);
}
```

You are not using ViewData["BZQUESTIONS"] in your view

Comment: @HenkHolterman the views model is an IEnumberable<CMS.Models.form_field>

Comment: @RichardK, I don't understand, it should have worked! Where do you get the null error? bsdb is null before you call bsdb.form_field? If not, after the call bquery is null?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting the exception could be that your query isn't returning any value actually.So,make sure that the query contains at least one element before being passed as the SelectList source.For example,try something along these lines:

```
if(bquery.Any())
 {
   ViewData["BZQUESTIONS"] = new SelectList(bquery,"ID","DATID","CAPTION");
 }
else
{
   // Add code here to address there being of no element returned by the query 
}   
return View();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the actual code contains IEnumerable not IEnumberable
2. int is a value type and therefore, is never null.  These where clauses are unnecessary.
3. You are creating an anonymous object, so the model ends up not being of the expected type, which is why it failed when you tried DivHenr's solution.  Do not select an anonymous object.
4. Also, force evaluation of your query and pass it to the model parameter of the view method, (instead of to viewdata).

Your query and action should be 
 -

```
  return View(  
       (from b in bsdb.form_field
       where b.CAPTION != null
       select b)
       .ToList() );
```